# Unhandled Exceptions in ASP.Net IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, unhandled-exception

**IDE: VS 2010


OS: Windows 7


IIS: 7.5


Mode: Integrated.


.Net: 4


Language: C#**

I have an asp.net application (not MVC) and I'm trying to catch all unhandled exceptions.

I've tried with global.asax -> Application_Error, but I read that because of the integrated mode -> I can't do that.

I'd appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Comment: So what happened when you tried in the global?

Comment: Nothing. It never got to the Application_Error method.
p.s.
The request which causes the error is using AJAX... (If that's relevant..)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already found a solution, but if not - or if anyone else has the same question - have a look at Elmah (https://code.google.com/p/elmah/). Simple to implement, great to use. Captures all unhandled exceptions with full details.

Comment: Problem is that I still needs to had Elmah.LogError whenever I'm not in the main thread.